# Can we add fixed buttons on top of bars in highcharts bar chart

Tags: highcharts

Hi we want to explore a feature, where we can add html buttons on top of bars in highcharts bar chart

[Highcharts Bar Chart Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QcYK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the buttons after chart creation process by using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class.

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    const chart = this;

    chart.series[0].points.forEach(function(point) {
      chart.renderer.button(
          'Hold',
          point.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
          point.plotY
        )
        .attr({
          align: 'center'
        })
        .add();
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u42h13eb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button